# How to recall this struct?

Tags: xcode, struct

how to recall this stryc?

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var street: String
    var city: String
    var postalCode: String

    func printAddress() -> String {
        return """
\(name)
\(street)
\(city)
\(postalCode)
"""
    }
}
```

I expect to have an address in different lines like the method, for example

> Well Smith
>   streetnumber this one
>   lalaland
>   19890

but result comes back in struct form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "recall struct" but if you want to print it in the expected format simply use `printAddress()`

```
let user = User(name: "name", street: "street", city: "city", postalCode: "postalCode")
print(user.printAddress())
```

Output:

> name
>   street
>   city
>   postalCode